# mocking angular service for testing controllers

Tags: angularjs, rest, maven, unit-testing, jasmine

let me present first the scenario.

this is my angular code.

```
//this is my controller
function viewUserProfile($scope, $http, svcUserInfo) {
    svcUserInfo.userInfo(null, function(data) {
        $scope.profile = loadProfile(data);
    }, function() {
        Console.log('Error getting User info.');
    });
}
```

so basically i am just loading a profile object on $scope.profile (e.g first name, last name,etc) using svcUserInfo REST service.

the service is created like this:

```
anythingHere.factory('svcUserInfo', ['$resource', function($resource) {
        return $resource(SVC_USER, null, {
            userInfo: {method: 'GET'}
        });
    }]);
```

now this one works perfectly so just assume other declarations or initialization before and after those codes.

now i am writing test codes using jasmine-maven-plugin here 
what i want to achieve is to mock the service with and populate $scope.profile. and this is what i have so far:

```
describe('User Profile Controller', function() {
    var rootScope, scope, 
    location = {}, route = {}, http = {}, userProfCtrl, 
    mockSvcUserInfo, userInfoPromise;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    beforeEach(module(MOD_USERPROF));
    beforeEach(module(function($provide){
        $provide.factory('svcUserInfo', ['$q', function($q) {
            var profile = {
                nameType: 'Personal Name',
                firstName: 'Joseph',
                lastName: 'Bada',
                email: 'email@email.com',
                hasReferrer: false,
                referrer: null,
                country: 'myCountry',
                state: 'myState',
                city: 'myCIty',
                address1: 'this is address1',
                address2: 'this is address2',
                zipcode: '9999',
                phone: '+191234567',
                maxProduct: '2'
            };
          function userInfo(data){
            if(userInfoPromise){
              return $q.when(profile);
            } else {
              return $q.reject();
            }
          }
          return{
            userInfo: userInfo
          };
        }]);
    }));
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, svcUserInfo){
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        rootScope = $rootScope.$new();
        mockSvcUserInfo = svcUserInfo;
        spyOn(mockSvcUserInfo, 'userInfo').and.callThrough();
        userProfCtrl = $controller(CTRL_USERPROF, {
            $scope: scope,
            svcUserInfo: mockSvcUserInfo,
            $rootScope: rootScope
        });
    }));
    it('should call the rest service for User Profile and populate profile', function() {
        userInfoPromise = true;
        scope.$digest();
        rootScope.$digest();
        expect(mockSvcUserInfo.userInfo).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(scope.profile).not.toBe(undefined); // or undefined anything like these
        it("profile object: " + JSON.stringify(scope.profile)); // this is for debugging purposes so that i can check if scope.profile has values or not.
    });
});
```

now on the spec i expect that after mockSvcUserInfo.user have been called.
then scope.profile must be populated/initialized since base on my code on the controller is that on successful call of the service, $scope.profile must be populated.
the result of this so far is that scope.profile goes undefined

i based my test codes from here:
http://www.sitepoint.com/mocking-dependencies-angularjs-tests/#mocking-methods-returning-promises

please help me, thanks

**EDIT**
I have updated the code coming from the first answer

```
it('should call the rest service for User Profile', inject(function($rootScope,$controller,svcUserInfo) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    rootScope = $rootScope.$new();
    userInfoPromise = true;
    mockSvcUserInfo = svcUserInfo;
    spyOn(mockSvcUserInfo, 'userInfo').and.callThrough();
    userProfCtrl = $controller(CTRL_USERPROF, {
        $scope: scope,
        svcUserInfo: mockSvcUserInfo,
        $rootScope: rootScope
    });
    scope.$digest();
    rootScope.$digest();
    expect(mockSvcUserInfo.userInfo).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(scope.profile).not.toBe([]);
    it("hello" + JSON.stringify(scope.profile));
}));
```

still scope.profile is undefined

Comment: You can debug the code in browser like normal js code. Put breakpoint and see if the controller function is instantiated.

Comment: i dont know how to do that.
i run the test on command prompt mvn clean install. thats also one of the problem i cant have a good look on debugging the tests

Comment: From the browser that karma opens, click the debug button. The new tab\window will run your test. Open developer console, and select you controller scripts in the source tab and put breakpoint on the controller. Refresh the page.

Comment: man i just tried your suggestion and it doesn't went in into the service, (coming from the controller)
is my $provide module correct? $q for REST services? is that okay?

Answer (score 0):

I think i know the problem.

You set `userInfoPromise` to true in your test, but your controller is created in the setup process, and by the time you set the boolean value the service call is done.

Either set `userInfoPromise` inside `beforeeach` or move the controller creation itno the test.

Comment: man, thanks for the answer please check my edit if thats how you portray it. still the scope.profile is undefined

Comment: i've also tried userInfo to just return $q.when(profile) so if the problem is with the var userInfoPromise, it would be eliminated. but the same problem still continues